# Безопасность Базы Данных

Tags: безопасность, php, база-данных

В прошлый вопрос был о безопасности пользовательских данных. С этим вопросом разобрался. Достал книжки и прочитал. Решение нашел в sh1($salt, $pepper);

Но ведь кроме взлома пользовательских данных могут и взломать БД, что еще хуже приведет к потере всех данных. Как с этим бороться? Что предлагаете? В какую сторону смотреть?

Ну, про инъекцию знаю. Он следующий в списке, что должен рассмотреть.

P.S Я только начинаю веб программирование и безопасность. Так что прошу ответы для этого уровня :)

Comment: > решение нашел в sh1($salt, $pepper);

Если еще успеваете, перебейте на более серьезный алгоритм (sha512, например). sha1 уже считается ненадежным.

Comment: Я только что читаю про алгоритмы хеширования. Планирую использовать двойное хеширование с помощью разных алгоритмов и плюс придумать свой алгоритм, типа salt1/2 и тд. Думаю смогу так повысить безопасность. Как думаете?

Comment: @navi1893, вообще да, но не так сильно, как лишние сто раундов все того же хеша. Злоумышленник, который получил доступ к вашим хешам, скорее всего имеет доступ и к алгоритмам, вопрос останется только в скорости подбора, и чем сильнее алгоритм, тем ему будет сложнее. т.е. все равно все упирается в сложность конкретного алгоритма и количество циклов (посмотрите функцию crypt, там по умолчанию sha512 прогоняется 5000 раз).
Вообще лучше не выдумывать свои схемы, если не освоен какой-то курс криптографии. Есть много очень интересных атак, про которые вы можете забыть или вообще не знать.

Answer (score 5):

Не используйте рутового юзера (root). Создайте пользователя, и ограничьте его права, запретите к удалять базу, создавать базу, удалять\модифицировать таблицы  etc.
Всегда фильтруйте все получаемые из вне данные, так как в них могут внедрить sql инъекцию.
Для каждой базы, используйте отдельного пользователя со своими правами доступа.

Comment: А если мне самому нужно будет удалять, создавать БД?

Comment: @navi1893 в этом случае используйте рута, само собой. Я имел в виду пользователей, под которыми Ваши сайты (приложения) будут обращаться к БД.

Answer (score 4):

Безопасность доступа к БД это работа не программиста, а системного администратора. В его обязанности входит правильно настроить сервер для безопасной работы. Но помните одно - что человек придумал, то другой человек сможет поломать. Первая фраза в моей настольной книге "Безопасность в системах *nix" - "Самый устойчивый по безопасности сервер - это тот который не подключён к сети и закрыт в коробке, и то не на 100%". Для минимизации возможности удаления записей в БД с помощью sql-инъекций почитайте про [вьюхи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/47031/) . И самое главное "паранойя". Старайтесь проверять все входящие данные.

Comment: Бывают и такие инъекции: ![SQL injection](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/6282/dropdatabase.jpg)

Comment: Поэтому и надо фильтровать все данные из вне!)